# How to resend verification email in play authenticate?

Tags: playframework-2.2, play-authenticate

I almost feel stupid for asking, but I can't figure out how to resend a verification email to a user who can't login using email & password on Play Authenticate. I.e. a user signed up for an account, the token on the verification email has expired, and a new verification email is required.

I understand the original verification email is sent after the user account is created and subsequently logged in, but I can't figure out how to do it with the user not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have your order of events wrong, the email is sent after the account is created and BEFORE they log in. If they have already logged in, then they must have validated the email. If they never validated the email, I believe you just need to ask the user to re-signup and a new email will be sent.

..Chet